# Automate manual introductory mouse clicks required for debugging

Tags: qt, c++11, debugging

I would like to find some programming errors concerning a GUI application with a QGraphicsView. To test manually, a mouse click onto the QGraphicsView component is required. Due to my imperfect mouse handling, various pixel coordinates result in a completely altered execution path with many changed variable values.

In addition, clicking manually for debugging purposes is rather time-expensive due to nasty errors (infinite loops, SIGSEVs, ...).

How is it possible to automate such a task like mouse-clicking similar to unit tests (with QTest) while being able to debug (control the program flow through breakpoints, ...)? Many thanks in advance.

EDIT: I am able to simulate the required mouse clicks in unit tests. I am not interested in executing a hopefully correct subprogram completely and get the values of some assertions as result, but in automating a sequence of mouse clicks to execute the program **up to the first breakpoint** (not until its end) and then carefully execute the single instructions manually. Perhaps, I've missed the link.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Qt QGraphicsView unit testing - how to keep the mouse in a "pressed" state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16299779/qt-qgraphicsview-unit-testing-how-to-keep-the-mouse-in-a-pressed-state)

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16299779/qt-qgraphicsview-unit-testing-how-to-keep-the-mouse-in-a-pressed-state to see how it can be done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved. The mouse clicks led to the execution of an algorithm. I was able to call the algorithm with fixed arguments directly during window initialization. In this way, I could intervene at a later moment and did not need to emulate mouse clicks anymore.